# Titanium to native android code causes app to crash unless data is removed

Tags: android, titanium, google-play

We originally wrote our app in titanium, but because titanium + android is so bad we made the devision to write V2 of the app in Java. App now works great but when the app updates from market, it crashes unless the app data is removed or V1 is uninstalled first.

How can I fix this issue? Is there a way of telling the market to fully remove app first before installing update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it is not possible. It appears you cannot choose to clear app data on an update :(

Answer (score 0):

> it crashes unless the app data is removed or V1 is uninstalled firstBlockquote

already thought about buggy code? it's difficult to help without code.

Comment: Well, the code works fine. Bothe the android titanium and native work with no problems. It is when the native version -updates- the titanium one. However if i clear app data it works. It is almost as if some app data is being left behind that is not compatible with the new one.

Comment: My question was not really programming related, it was how can i tell the market to do a clean install of the application (or warn this app will be removed first)

Comment: i don't think this is possible. you should use other names for your config file or databases to guarantee that the old stuff won't be used. this is the only way.

Comment: ok thanks. :) As you say it does appear to be the only way. It would be a very useful market option though me thinks.